# Material Autocomplete select dropdown getting error while onchange

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here is my code.

My problem : Cannot change the dropdown value. Getting error like Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

```
{formValues.map((element, index) => (
                <div className="row mt-2"  key={index}>                        
                    <div className='col-lg-4 mt-2'  key={index}>
                        <Autocomplete
                            multiple
                            name="assignee"
                            limitTags={2}
                            id="assignee"
                            options={ownerList}
                            defaultValue={[{'text': formValues[index].AssigneeName, 'id': formValues[index].AssigneeId }]}
                            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.text}
                             onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                                console.log(newValue[0].id); // this line am getting error like Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
                              
                              }}
      
                            disableClearable={true}
                            filterSelectedOptions
                            renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField
                            classes={{ root: classes.customTextField }}
                                {...params}
                                label="Select Assignee"
                                placeholder="Select Assignee"
                                className="auto-label"
                                
                            />
                            )}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                 ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you perhaps log `console.log(newValue)`? That would give you an insight on why you receive this error. Probably newValue[0] is undefined.

You can add optional chaining to prevent the Error. `console.log(newValue[0]?.id);`

Comment: When I on change the dropdown I getting the data like {id: 1, text: 'Raja'} when I use the console.log(newValue[0]). 

But getting the error, when I print the  console.log(newValue[0].id);

Comment: can you try to add optional chaining ? `console.log(newValue[0]?.id);`. Perhaps the onChange gets triggered before the list of options is initialized.